# How to edit The quantity in Cart view using Collection in C#!

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the code in ASP.NET C# 4.5 with  the following:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace SportsStore.Models
{
public class Cart
{
    private List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();
    public void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        CartLine line = lineCollection
        .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
        .FirstOrDefault();
        if (line == null)
        {
            lineCollection.Add(new CartLine
            {
                Product = product,
                Quantity = quantity
            });
        }
        else
        {
            line.Quantity += quantity;
        }
    }
    public void RemoveLine(Product product)
    {
        lineCollection.RemoveAll(l => l.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID);
    }

    public decimal ComputeTotalValue()
    {
        return lineCollection.Sum(e => e.Product.Price * e.Quantity);
    }
    public void Clear()
    {
        lineCollection.Clear();
    }
    public IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines
    {
        get { return lineCollection; }

    }
 }
   public class CartLine
   {
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
   }
}
```

There is a method RemoveLine(Product product) but 
I do not know how to create a method EditLine to edit  the quantity in the Cart view!
Please help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void EditLine(Product product, int quantity)
{
    CartLine line = lineCollection
    .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
    .FirstOrDefault();
    if (line != null)
    {
        line.Quantity += quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how to pass the parameter quantity to EditLine method ?